# Windows 7 - High CPU usage during idle time

Tags: windows-7, process, cpu-usage

I just noticed when I'm away from my laptop running Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit, after a while CPU fan starts high speed working, but anytime I return back to PC with first input by mouse/keyboard the process seems to terminates.

When I look in task manager's CPU usage history page, it shows 90-100% CPU usage for the past period of time, but for current time CPU usage is low around 0-10%, so I can't find the process using the CPU.
Every process explorer I know shows processes for right now, only one application is there logging history of processes at processhistory.sourceforge.net, but after testing, it seems that is not much informative, and I failed to make it showing past processes and their CPU usages.

How could I simply find the process causing this CPU usage?

Comment: run xperf to capture the CPU usage (open the cmd, run the xperf command, let Windows be idle and wait until you hear the fan again. Wait 30s, now move the move to stop the activity. Go back to the CMD and press a key to stop the logging. Zip and share the generated ETL file: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD (The Windows 8.1 SDK/WPT also works in Windows 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be switching to the Processes tab, sorting by CPU, and waiting.

Alternatively, add the CPU Time column on the Processes page to see which process has the most CPU time.

Note: Many programs (antivirus scans, Windows Search indexing, etc) only run while the computer is idle and pause while the computer is in use.

Comment: I don't have antivirus installed, So it may be just a regular update or indexing, right? Nice solution, are you sure it works, I turned the screen saver off, and I'm waiting to test.